# build a javascript callback function from php for chartjs

Tags: php, jquery, chart.js

I'm building a graph on a template using chartjs, works great but the labels are having rounding issues and could do with showing the currency symbol so i discovered i can use a callback function in the tooltip.

Now I'm creating the javascript in an array using php and then using json_encode to construct the chart data, when I run the code the content is rendered but now the tooltip has vanished.

A simplified version of the array building is as follows:

```
$dataSets             = array();

    $res                  = new stdClass();
    $res->label           = 'Client (paid)';
    $res->backgroundColor = $palette[0]->background_color;
    $res->stack           = 'Stack 0';
    $res->data            = array_values( $pi['client'] );
    $dataSets[0]          = $res;

    $title                = new stdClass();
    $title->display       = true;
    $title->text          = 'Invoices Breakdown';

    $callbacks            = new stdClass();
    $label                = new stdClass();

    $callbacks->label     = "
    function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';

        if (label) {
            label += ': £';
        }
        label += Math.round(tooltipItem.yLabel * 100) / 100;
        return label;
    }";

    $tooltips             = new stdClass();
    $tooltips->mode       = 'index';
    $tooltips->intersect  = false;
    $tooltips->callbacks  = $callbacks;

    $scales               = new stdClass();

    $xAxes                = array();
    $x                    = new stdClass();
    $x->stacked           = true;
    $xAxes[]              = $x;
    $scales->xAxes        = $xAxes;

    $yAxes                = array();
    $y                    = new stdClass();
    $y->stacked           = true;
    $yAxes[]              = $y;
    $scales->yAxes        = $yAxes;

    $ds                   = new stdClass();
    $ds->type             = 'bar';

    $data                 = new stdClass();
    $data->labels         = $months;
    $data->datasets       = $dataSets;
    $ds->data             = $data;

    $options              = new stdClass();
    $options->title       = $title;
    $options->tooltips    = $tooltips;
    $options->responsive  = true;
    $options->scales      = $scales;
    $ds->options          = $options;

    return $ds;
```

So as can be seen i insert the callback as a string (the working version didn't have the $callback object)

My code that outputs this object is this:

```
$chart = json_encode( $dataset );
$html .= '
    <canvas id="invoiceChart" width="100" height="50"></canvas>
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("invoiceChart").getContext("2d");    
        var invoiceChart = new Chart(ctx, ' . $chart . ')
    </script>';
```

So how would i insert a callback function in this way?

An example of the code rendered as $chart is:

```
<script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("invoiceChart").getContext("2d");    
        var invoiceChart = new Chart(ctx, {"type":"bar","data":{"labels":["Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec","Jan","Feb"],"datasets":[{"label":"Client (paid)","backgroundColor":"#784187","stack":"Stack 0","data":[0,2,655,75,31.5,0]},{"label":"Client (auth)","backgroundColor":"#DDDDDD","stack":"Stack 0","data":[0,5.4,925,971.03,1227.703,402]},{"label":"Client (draft)","backgroundColor":"#003D51","stack":"Stack 0","data":[0,0,0,0,0,761.667]},{"label":"Contractor (paid)","backgroundColor":"#EA9A24","stack":"Stack 1","data":[0,166.505,9.99,0,81.93,0]},{"label":"Contractor (auth)","backgroundColor":"#E6194B","stack":"Stack 1","data":[0,0,261.451,0,2361.165,90.915]},{"label":"Contractor (draft)","backgroundColor":"#3CB44B","stack":"Stack 1","data":[0,5.4,0,0,239.71300000000002,252.77800000000002]}]},"options":{"title":{"display":true,"text":"Invoices Breakdown"},"tooltips":{"mode":"index","intersect":false,"callbacks":{"label":"\r\n    function(tooltipItem, data) {\r\n        var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';\r\n\r\n        if (label) {\r\n            label += ': \u00a3';\r\n        }\r\n        label += Math.round(tooltipItem.yLabel * 100) \/ 100;\r\n        return label;\r\n    }"}},"responsive":true,"scales":{"xAxes":[{"stacked":true}],"yAxes":[{"stacked":true}]}}})
    </script>
```

As you can see (unsurprisingly) the callback function is surrounded by quotes (well it is a string right)

So how can I do this correctly?

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.3/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback

edit: just thought I can probably use a place holder and a search and replace but is there another solution?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

So i ended up replacing the string with "¬¬" and replacing this with the callback function. No solutions on how to do this and put the callback into the object provided by community.